# Issue with tree and labels in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I would like to place a label on the edge of a tree in a way that it breaks the edge. I tried something silly, by setting the background to white, but then I get the label to cover other nearby edges:

[image: Example]

Also I seems to have nodes with label with 2 digits being bigger. How can I make everything uniform?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance=15mm/#1}]
        \node [circle,draw] {0}
        child[very thick,red] {node [thin, black,circle,draw] {$1$} edge from parent node [fill=white] {$s_1$}}
        child[very thick,blue] {node [thin, black,circle,draw] {$2$}
            child[very thick, red] {node [thin, black,circle,draw] {$3$}}
            child[very thick, blue] {node [thin, black,circle,draw] {$4$}}
            child[very thick, orange] {node [thin, black,circle,draw] {$8$}}
            edge from parent node [fill=white] {$s_2$} }
        child[very thick,orange] {node [thin, black,circle,draw] {$6$}}
        child[very thick,orange] {node [thin, black,circle,draw] {$7$}}
        child[very thick,blue] {node [thin, black,circle,draw] {$11$}
            child[very thick, red] {node [thin, black,circle,draw] {$10$}}
            child[very thick, blue] {node [thin, black,circle,draw] {$9$}}
            child[very thick, orange] {node [thin, black,circle,draw] {$5$}}
        }
        child[very thick,red] {node [thin, black,circle,draw] {$12$}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please have alook atthe answer if it suits your requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With use of the `forest` package the tree code is shorter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\forestset{
  EL/.style={% abbreviation for Edge Label
             edge label={node[midway, font=\small, text=black,
                         fill=white, inner sep=2pt]{$#1$}} 
             }
          }% end of forestset
  
\begin{forest}
for tree = {
% node style
    circle,
    draw, 
    minimum size = 1.5em,
    inner sep=0pt,
    math content,
% tree style
    edge={very thick},
    s sep=3mm,
    l sep=12mm,
           }
[0,
    [1, edge=red, EL=s_1]
    [2, edge=blue,EL=s_2,fit=band
        [3, edge=orange]
        [4, edge=blue]
        [8, edge=orange]
    ]
    [6,edge=orange]
    [7,edge=orange]
    [11,edge=blue,fit=band
        [10,edge=red]
        [9, edge=blue]
        [5, edge=orange]
    ]
    [12, edge=red]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum (1):**
if you like increase distance between node "6" and "7" only, the simplest is insert phantom node between them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\forestset{
  EL/.style={% shortens for (my) edge label
             edge label={node[midway, font=\small, text=black,
                         fill=white, inner sep=2pt]{$#1$}}
             }
          }% end of forestset

\begin{forest}
for tree = {
% node style
    circle,
    draw,
    minimum size = 1.5em,
    inner sep=0pt,
    math content,
% tree style
    edge={very thick},
    s sep=3mm,
    l sep=12mm,
           }
[0,
    [1, edge=red, EL=s_1]
    [2, edge=blue,EL=s_2, fit=band
        [3, edge=orange]
        [4, edge=blue]
        [8, edge=orange]
    ]
    [6,edge=orange]
    [, phantom, no edge]  % <---
    [7,edge=orange]
    [11,edge=blue,fit=band
        [10,edge=red]
        [9, edge=blue]
        [5, edge=orange]
    ]
    [12, edge=red]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum (2):**
If you like to have narrower image of tree, you can set:

- `s sep=1mm` s
- remove `fit=band` options at the bottom level of tree
- reduce font size of edge labels to `font=\footnotesize`
- push edge label position lower with replacing`midway` with `pos=0.65`
- reduce font size of tree's nodes with adding option `font=\small` in `\for tree` settings
- reduce node size to `minimum size=1.2em
  New MWE then is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\forestset{
  EL/.style={% abbreviation for Edge Label
             edge label={node[pos=0.65, font=\footnotesize, text=black,
                         fill=white, inner sep=2pt]{$#1$}}
             }
          }% end of forestset

\begin{forest}
for tree = {
% node style
    circle,
    draw,
    font=\small,
    minimum size = 1.2em,
    inner sep=0pt,
    math content,
% tree style
    edge={very thick},
    s sep=2mm,
    l sep=12mm,
           }
[0,
    [1, edge=red, EL=s_1]
    [2, edge=blue,EL=s_2,
        [3, edge=orange]
        [4, edge=blue]
        [8, edge=orange]
    ]
    [6,edge=orange]
    [7,edge=orange]
    [11,edge=blue,
        [10,edge=red]
        [9, edge=blue]
        [5, edge=orange]
    ]
    [12, edge=red]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

which produce:

[image]

Comment: this is great! thanks. Is possible to control the separation between 6 and 7 only? I figured how to do for 3-4-8 and 10-9-5, but not for only 6 and 7. Thx!

Comment: @geguze, if you like increase distance between node "6" and "7" only,  the simplest is insert phantom node between them. see addendum to answer.

Comment: I have used your code, but I am still running into the same problem as in my initial picture, when I need to squeeze a tree into a subfigure. The `fill=white` is covering nearby edges. Of course I could change the `s sep` and `l sep` to avoid this, but this picture needs to be tight (page limits). I was wondering: can one define a custom dash (using `dash pattern')? I can then adapt the pattern so that the line is off when there is a label. Any idea on how to that? Thx!

Comment: @geguze, i add the second addendum, which MWE produce narrower tree. If you like to change edges, use `edge={orange,dashed,thin}` options.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        every node/.style={% standard style for all nodes no repetition required every time
            thin, 
            black,
            draw,
            circle,
            inner sep=1pt,% space around the text in the circle
            text width=10pt,%uniform circles minimum size
            text centered
        },
    level/.style={
        sibling distance=15mm/#1
    },
        level distance=5em% can vary to suit 
]
        \node [] {0}
        child[very thick,red] {node [] {$1$} edge from parent node [draw=none,fill=white] {$s_1$}}
        child[very thick,blue] {node [] {$2$}
            child[very thick, red] {node [] {$3$}}
            child[very thick, blue] {node [] {$4$}}
            child[very thick, orange] {node [] {$8$}}
            edge from parent node [fill=white,draw=none] {$s_2$} }
        child[very thick,orange] {node [] {$6$}}
        child[very thick,orange] {node [] {$7$}}
        child[very thick,blue] {node [] {$11$}
            child[very thick, red] {node [] {$10$}}
            child[very thick, blue] {node [] {$9$}}
            child[very thick, orange] {node [] {$5$}}
        }
        child[very thick,red] {node [] {$12$}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```